# How to override 'H1 page title' and how to group content types?

Tags: forms, theming

I have 2 questions:

1. Let's say you have a content type named `Page` and a theme as in this example:

   [image]

   This theme shows the content type name Page (in the picture it shows "About us" as a H1 page title). My question is: How can I change the name that will be shown on the page as a H1 page title, by not creating a bunch of new content types with the appropriate name? So in short: I have a content type named `Page`, when adding new content it shows `Page` as a H1 page title. How can I override that so that it says Content , About us etc ...?
2. Is there a way to group content types? Let's say you created 10 of them (Pizza , Fries , Fish, red wine, white wine, etc ...) and you want to group them so that when you go to "add new content" you don't have to view all 10 of them but only 2 groups (Food, Drinks) that hold the corresponding items?
   So when you click Food it shows you the Pizza, Fries, Fish etc ...

Comment: i  don't know how to make it more clear?

Comment: I tried to improve your question (mostly by including the screenprint you refer to). I think it is a bit more clear, though I still do not understand question "1" in it: I don't see anything about "Page" in your picture. And the way you use the term "content type" seems strange to me, could it be a "node" you are talking about instead? Or do you mean the menu item named "Content type"? Please enhance your question to clarify that. Also, I suggest you remove your "question 2" here, and move it to a brand new question (the rule here is like "1 question at a time" ...). Just trying to help ...

Comment: OK, so if you look at the picture you have About us in white letters surrounded by black and light blue colors. About us is actually the name of the Content type (Structure > Content type). So when you add new content (Add content > About Us) you always get About Us as the title. That is set in the Theme and i like it that way. So lets say you have content type named Article. You would always have Article above every new content you create. My question is how can you override that so i have a different title but the same content type.

Comment: As i stand now i have to create a new Content type so i have it say what i need. But whit that i can live because i have only 12 of them so i don't mind . My Question for now is can you group your content types in administration . As I said i have 12 Content types but i only use 4 of them. How can i group the others that i don't use. I can create  a user and hide the other content types, but is there a different way ?

Comment: Thanks for the extra comments (info). I suggest you EDIT your question to integrate those 2 comments somehow. Doing so might help to get enough review-votes to have your question reopened. After which you may get actual answers to your question (now that it is closed nobody can answer it as you probably know). PS: I need to digest your comments a bit more, but I "may" have a suggestion for you that may work (later on).